# How do I fix Notification Centre? It is blank in "Recents" mode

Tags: notifications

Within the last two weeks, the right tab in Notification Centre ("Notifications)" became completely blank, without warning, and with no apparent trigger. The sort order mode is "Recents".

How can this be fixed?

I have tried to restart the Macbook in question, and Notification Centre itself using Activity Monitor.

(Mac OS X Version 10.11.6 (15G31))

Answer (score 1):

A workaround: change the sort order to "Recents by App" in the Notifications section of System Preferences.

Comment: This isn't an "answer", especially since it is really additional information to your question.

Comment: If I hadn't worked this out (whilst typing the question) I would have considered it a candidate, incomplete answer - in the absence of anything better. But it's against SE rules or best practice, I am happy to delete and can  add as a comment to the question.